# Pass 'this' as parameter

Tags: javascript, object, garbage-collection, this

Imagine that I do something like this:

An instance of Obj1 is added to a namespaced section within the global APP object.

```
APP.namespace.obj = new Obj1();
```

From The Obj1 constructor, I instantiate another object like this:

```
var var1 = new Obj2({someobj: this});
```

This is passed as a parameter (pointing to obj1). 
In Obj2, I set the passed object as a property:

```
This.someobj = options.someobj;
```

It allows me to call prototype methods on Obj1. 
Do any of these objects ever get garbage collected? 
How can I destroy these objects when I don't need either of them anymore?

The scope in which I do this is, is to make controllers (obj1) that can operate on views (obj2).
But I want to delegate methods that manage other views as well + calls to the back end from the controller (obj1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i know, as long as `APP.namespace.obj` exists, they can't be garbage collected.

Maybe use an pub/sub pattern (observer pattern) between your views and controllers. This way the tight coupling should be removed.

Comment: Considering the fact that this is a single page application, I can see how this is a really bad thing. When one namespaces his global APP object into models/views in Backbone, I suppose that it is doomed to get overloaded over time. Can that even be right?

Comment: Well, from what i know, `Backbone` isn't right for long living single page apps because it is hard to have clean memory. Instead, `Ember.js` and `ExtJs` offer a programming model that should prevent memory problems as well as takes care of most of the memory management for you. Maybe study how they are approaching this problem could help you.

Comment: If the single page application is not destined to run for a long period of time, than memory shouldn't be that much of a problem, in my opinion.

Comment: Hmm that's bad. It's supposed to run for a long time. For The pub sub, I think that I might face the same problem, but I'll study the topic nevertheless

Comment: If you search `ember.js vs angularjs vs backbone.js` on google you should get a nice overview of the + /- of each framework and tells you what to consider when choosing it. I personally work with `ExtJs` and they are using a `pub/sub system` to solve this problem. Also controllers have references to views and models but not the other way around. In `ember.js` if I remember well, they are using a life-cycle system.

Comment: Thanks. we're using backbone already at work, so I guess I'll have to work out some structural changes myself. Thanks for the tip though!